# How can I create a PATH between two elements without specifying its coordinates in SVG

Tags: javascript, svg

Imagine I have a javascript library that is arbitrarily manipulating the position of two elements. I want to draw a spline (`path`) that starts at one element and ends on the other one, like:

```
<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="5" />
<circle cx="100" cy="50" r="5" />
<path d="M 369 320 C 426 320 386 304 444 304"/>
```

Now, I thought about transforming the origin of the path to match the center of the circle, but that would mean "hardcoding" the coordinates. If I want to move the circle, I would have to recalculate the path data.

So, question (1) how can I do something like that without resorting to javascript? and (2) **iff** javascript is the sole solution for this problem, then which technique (including libraries) would you recommend that would ease the task of allowing the reference objects to be arbitrarily moved and automate the necessary path recalculations?

Comment: Are you in control of the JS that is moving the elements around? I would suggest grouping them together (`<g>...</g>`) and then transforming this group as a unit.

Comment: In SVG, all is based on absolute coordinates (according to the viewport). There is nothing like object-relative positions.

Comment: I would research libraries that have done this before ... searching for `flowchart in svg` turns up a few possibilities